# Simple Protocol Buffers program works when compiled with g++ but not clang++

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers, clang++

I'm trying to use [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) in a simple C++ program. When I compile with `g++` the program executes and exits normally. When I compile with `clang++` the program fails, complaining that `pointer being freed was not allocated`.

#### Protocol Buffer Message Definition

```
package test;

message Test {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}
```

#### Main Class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.pb.h"

int main(void) {
    // Build the original message
    test::Test original;
    original.set_id(0);
    original.set_name("original");

    // Serialize the original message
    int size = original.ByteSize();
    char data[size];
    original.SerializeToArray(data, size);

    // Deserialize the data into a previously initialized message
    test::Test success;
    success.set_id(1);
    success.set_name("success");
    success.ParseFromArray(data, size);
    std::cout << success.id() << ": " << success.name() << std::endl;

    // Deserialize the data into an uninitialized message
    test::Test failure;
    failure.ParseFromArray(data, size); // FAILS HERE WITH CLANG++
    std::cout << failure.id() << ": " << failure.name() << std::endl;
}
```

#### g++ Output

```
theisenp$ g++ test.pb.cc main.cpp -lprotobuf -o g++.out
theisenp$ ./g++.out 
0: original
0: original
```

#### clang++ Output

```
theisenp$ clang++ test.pb.cc main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -stdlib=libstdc++ -o clang++.out
theisenp$ ./clang++.out 
0: original
clang++.out(9948,0x7fff71195310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff72ed6330: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm new to both Protocol Buffers and Clang so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

### Edit

Some clarification on compiler versions. I'm running OSX Mavericks (10.9.1). By default, Mavericks maps calls to `gcc` and `g++` to `clang` and `clang++` respectively. I've installed `gcc` 4.8.2 independently and overridden the default behavior.

#### g++ Version

```
theisenp$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Configured with: ../configure
    --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
    --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2
    --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++
    --program-suffix=-4.8
    --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4
    --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2
    --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08
    --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog018
    --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl011
    --with-system-zlib
    --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
    --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes
    --enable-stage1-checking
    --enable-checking=release
    --enable-lto
    --disable-werror
    --enable-plugin
    --disable-nls
    --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

#### clang++ Version

```
theisenp$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this -- g++ 4.8.2 and clang++ 3.3 produce identical output for me on Linux.  What platform are you on?  BTW, the last line of your main function prints the friends of `success`; I think you meant to print `failure`.

Comment: I am suspicious of the `-stdlib=libstdc++` parameter.  It shouldn't be necessary to specify this -- Clang should use the appropriate library for your platform by default.  If you're on mac with XCode 5, `g++` is actually a symlink to `clang++` and I think `libc++` (not `libstdc++`) is the default.  In this case, your error is that you are forcing it to use a different stdlib than libprotobuf was built with, which would easily explain the crash.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean to print failure, that was a copy-paste mistake. I've updated the question with platform and compiler information. I can't remember if I built `libprotobuf` with `clang++` or `g++`, so I'll investigate that next. At the moment, the clang compile without the `--stdlib` flag fails with an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error

Comment: @KentonVarda That fixed it, thanks! If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

I had remapped clang to gcc to get msgpack to compile (which I had also been testing) and forgot that I had apparently also used it to compile protobuf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments, it's important that libprotobuf is compiled with the same stdlib that you use when compiling your code, since libprotobuf uses STL types (especially `std::string`) in its interface.  If you've installed GCC 4.8, it will use GCC's libstdc++ 4.8.  The Clang shipped with Xcode, meanwhile, will use whatever stdlibs ship with Xcode, so even if you tell it `--stdlib=libstdc++`, it may be an incompatible version.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem may be here:

```
int size = original.ByteSize();
char data[size];
```

Variable length arrays are not valid C++ (they are permitted in C99), they are a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

I'd suggest using a dynamically allocated buffer and see if the problem persists. There is some discussion about clang and VLAs circa 2010 [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Variable-length-arrays-are-not-permitted-in-C-td210730.html).

Comment: Clang supports some VLAs in C++ (including primitive arrays), and will give a clear compilation error for any case that isn't supported.  So, that's not the issue.